# Jquery Cycle2 Progessive Loading displaying <script> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle2, cycle2

I am trying to setup jQuery cycle2 to progressively load a set of images. There are multiple `.slider` objects on the page which need to load images progressively.

This is the HTML

```html
<li class="slider"><img title="Company Name" alt="Company Name" src="/photos/listings/company-name6.jpg">
<script class="other-slides" type="text/cycle">[<img title='Ad 6 Auto wide' alt='Ad 6 Auto wide' src='/photos/listings/ad-6-auto-wide.jpg'>
<img title='Ad 6 Auto wide' alt='Ad 6 Auto wide' src='/photos/listings/ad-6-auto-wide1.jpg'>
<img title='Ad 6 Auto wide' alt='Ad 6 Auto wide' src='/photos/listings/ad-6-auto-wide2.jpg'>
<img title='Ad 6 Auto wide' alt='Ad 6 Auto wide' src='/photos/listings/ad-6-auto-wide3.jpg'>
<img title='Ad 6 Auto wide' alt='Ad 6 Auto wide' src='/photos/listings/ad-6-auto-wide4.jpg'>
]</script></li>
```

This is the JavaScript

```js
    $('.slider').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.cycle({
        slides: '> img',
        sync: true,
        progressive: function() {
           var slides = $('.other-slides', $this).html();
           return $.parseJSON( slides );
        },
        speed: 1500,
        timeout: 4000,
        loader: true
    });
});
```

The initial picture is shown and then it cycles and shows this
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqWfx.png)

Comment: For all of the effort put in to jQuery that will get version locked for all of eternity you could instead learn pure JavaScript, not get version locked, not suffer massive performance hits on an already extremely high level / low performance language and greatly increase your skills.

Comment: @John This question is coming up to four years old and was solving a problem on an existing system at the time. I don't really see the need for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. If you look at the [progressive example](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/progressive.php) on the cycle2 website it notes that the script tag needs to contain a JSON array of the slides to be loaded. Each individual slide needs to be wrapped in double quotes and the slides separated with a comma.

Here's the updated JSON for the progressive slides:

```
<script class="other-slides" type="text/cycle">
[
    "<img title='Ad 6 Auto wide' alt='Ad 6 Auto wide' src='/photos/listings/ad-6-auto-wide.jpg'>",
    "<img title='Ad 6 Auto wide' alt='Ad 6 Auto wide' src='/photos/listings/ad-6-auto-wide1.jpg'>",
    "<img title='Ad 6 Auto wide' alt='Ad 6 Auto wide' src='/photos/listings/ad-6-auto-wide2.jpg'>",
    "<img title='Ad 6 Auto wide' alt='Ad 6 Auto wide' src='/photos/listings/ad-6-auto-wide3.jpg'>",
    "<img title='Ad 6 Auto wide' alt='Ad 6 Auto wide' src='/photos/listings/ad-6-auto-wide4.jpg'>"
]
</script>
```

And here's a [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m7061fm7/).